# Change MySQL log-error to a relative Windows path

Tags: mysql, logging, wamp, relative-path

In WAMP, in **C:\wamp\mysql\my.ini** I have the following line:

```
log-error=C:/wamp/logs/mysql_error.log
```

which works fine. The logs go to `C:/wamp/logs/mysql_error.log`.

But if I change it to

```
log-error=../logs/mysql_error.log
```

or to

```
log-error="../logs/mysql_error.log"
```

the file `mysql_error.log` is not created (or if it already exists, the logs are not written into it).

How can I use a **relative path** in this line?

---

**Details**:

- WAMP5 Version 1.6.6

  - MySQL 5.0.27

Comment: at what actual path you want to keep error logs....also mysql service restart will be required to write on new path.

Comment: @ZafarMalik , in the same place (here `C:/wamp/logs/mysql_error.log`), but without using an absolute path. I want to use a relative path and to achieve the same behavior, because after a while I want to move the file on another server where the absolute path is different.